# What should be fixed to put in a slideshow on the main page to position-3 of Protostar, configuration's attribute are made

Tags: joomla-3.x, configuration

evereody! Please, tell me what should be fixed to put in  a slideshow on the main page to position-3 of Protostar (in stead of default image). On  the other pages it works pretty well. Ive'been using rockspoket module and CK module - the same negative result.  configuration's  attribute are made
Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome. Honestly, I don't know about other users, but personally I am having hard-time to understand what the problem is and what you are asking. Can you try improve your question and make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

I can fix the problem.
As a matter of fact i created one more main menu before and deactivated default menu. But I should have selected both pages (my new home page and default home page from deactivated default menu) to put in slideshow module.(Home default page works even deactivated)